# writing a file using write.table from R

Tags: r

I imported a text file into R and performed some operations.
When i try to write the file using write.table, the generated text file has inverted commas at the beginning and the end of each lines.
I do not need these.
Any way to remove this using R?

"001723514161chfbed5e77A 59310057920012012-08-30011578579959"
"003537255515ch3a6381b7A 59310057920012011-06-05011578579959"

Code:

```
write.table(my_data_updated, "mydata2.txt",row.names = F,col.names = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `quote=F` for example:

### Data

```
my_data_updated <- c("001723514161chfbed5e77A 59310057920012012-08-30011578579959", "003537255515ch3a6381b7A 59310057920012011-06-05011578579959")
```

## Write table

```
write.table(my_data_updated, "mydata2.txt",row.names = F,col.names = F, quote=F)
```